# Remove images from remote repository, but not developer repositories

Tags: git, repo

I'm working on a project where my client is loading data on the server and every time I pull the server changes, I get all the new images.

My repo is now 3.3gb large, which is unmanageable. I've added the images folder to my local .gitignore, but how to I remove the images folder from the GIT repo to make it 20mb instead of 3.3gb without removing the images from any of the developers computers?

Thank you!

Comment: Define "repo" as you use it here. Git is distributed, which means that everywhere it's in use is a repo.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you'd like to remove images that have been committed to (or existed upon creation of) a remote repository. Since you've added the directory to .gitignore, you can safely remove images from any computer and it won't affect others.

In this case, log into the remote server and delete the files *after updating its .gitignore file*, either with a pull or manual change.

To delete files directly on BitBucket, follow [this guide](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/293052/how-to-delete-a-filefolder-from-bitbucket).

> I went to the remote repository's website > Source > select branch > select folder > select file to be deleted > Edit > Delete > Commit.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! So since I have .gitignore already ignoring the images folder, I can just delete the images from Bitbucket without losing the images?

Comment: That should be the case. If it shows files staged for commit after deleting, then something is wrong.